# How do I save my new output data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I started out with a labeled data set and have now changed that to number data through using `MultiColumnLabelEncoder`. I now want to save the new output to a CSV file. How do I go about doing that, code below and an image of the data I want to save.

```
class MultiColumnLabelEncoder:
def __init__(self,columns = None):
    self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode
    
def fit(self,X,y=None):
    return self # not relevant here

def transform(self,X):
    '''
    Transforms columns of X specified in self.columns using
    LabelEncoder(). If no columns specified, transforms all
    columns in X.
    '''
    output = X.copy()
    if self.columns is not None:
        for col in self.columns:
            output[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(output[col])
    else:
        for colname,col in output.iteritems():
            output[colname] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col)
    return output

def fit_transform(self,X,y=None):
    return self.fit(X,y).transform(X)


MultiColumnLabelEncoder(columns = ['Title','Description']).fit_transform(data)
```

[image: Data Output]

Comment: Assuming that you're showing a `pandas.DataFrame`, you can use the [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) method to dump the dataframe to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the pandas to_csv() method. Check out this link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
df.to_csv('filepath/filename.csv')
```